# Java: Array asterisk printing for values

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to print asterisks based on the number of times a dices side is rolled (all through an array). I am coming across an issue with the printing of the dice side (i) before the asterisks. Also, I'm getting two zeroes out of nowhere and don't know where they're coming from.
I'd appreciate the help.

My code:

```
public class Histogram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int numRoles = 100;
        int[] amountRoles = new int[7]; // amountRoles Holds the array

        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) 
        amountRoles[i] = 0; // Set 0
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numRoles; i++) 
            {
                int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
                amountRoles[die1]++; // Increments 
            }
            System.out.println("The die was rolled " + numRoles + " times, its six value's counts are:");
            for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("Side " + i + " was rolled " + amountRoles[i]+ " times out of " + numRoles + ".");
                // Prints each sides value (i) alongside with how many times it was rolled (amountRoles[i]).
                System.out.println(); // Formatting Line
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < amountRoles.length; i++) // Iterates through amountRoles
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < amountRoles[i]; j++) // Loop through amountRoles[i]
            {
                System.out.print("" + "*");
            }
            System.out.println(i + " "  + amountRoles[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My output:

```
The die was rolled 100 times, its six value's counts are:
Side 1 was rolled 11 times out of 100.
Side 2 was rolled 19 times out of 100.
Side 3 was rolled 19 times out of 100.
Side 4 was rolled 17 times out of 100.
Side 5 was rolled 16 times out of 100.
Side 6 was rolled 18 times out of 100.
0 0 (Where are these zeroes coming from?)
***********1 11
*******************2 19
*******************3 19
*****************4 17
****************5 16
******************6 18
```

An example output I am aiming for:

```
[1]     ******************* 19
[2]     ************ 12
[3]     ********************* 21
[4]     ******************** 20
[5]     ************* 13
[6]     *************** 15
```

Comment: Hint: Why do you need an array of size 7 to hold the number of times a 6-sided dice rolled a specific result?

Comment: As per @Paul comment, that is where the `0 0` is coming from, you start out at `i = 0`, which has no value, thus you get `0 0`

Comment: I think the underlying challenge you're having is that arrays in java are zero based, but you're kinda treating them like they're not.  In other words the first element of the array is at index 0, so you should put the rolls count for 1 at index 0.  Also, using `System.out.print("some string");` followed by `System.out.println();` is kinda clunky.  Instead use `System.out.println("some string");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only answering your question an no other problems I see with the code, you are getting the `0 0` from `int i = 0`. Change this to `int i = 1` and no more `0 0`!

To get your values to print the way you need, you just need to simple move what you want to print before the `*` above the loop. In this case `[i]`, and move the amount each roll was below the `*` loop. Code is below. This should fix your stated problems.

```
for (int i = 1; i < amountRoles.length; i++) // Iterates through amountRoles
{
    System.out.print("[" + i + "]");
    for(int j = 0; j < amountRoles[i]; j++) // Loop through amountRoles[i]
    {
        System.out.print("" + "*");
    }
    System.out.println(" " + amountRoles[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're starting at zero?

also for the mid line

```
System.out.println(); // Formatting Line
```

the above can be removed and just add ln to the previous output.

I'd also use a variable to keep count of the string and then append it.

```
for (int i = 1; i < amountRoles.length; i++) // Iterates through amountRoles
    {
        String asterCount = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < amountRoles[i]; j++) // Loop through amountRoles[i]
        {
            asterCount += ("*");
        }
        System.out.println("[" +i +"]"+ "   "+ asterCount  + " "+ amountRoles[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I like the idea of a count variable, but OP might as well print there as well, since the count variable is only used in the print statement, and as a formatting preference, as opposed to summing an array, he is simply displaying the array using `*`.